SendProcessControlEvent:toPid: encountered an error: Error Code 8
I'm trying to install a WidgetKit app on the iOS Simulator, but I'm encountering an error that I can't resolve. The app fails to launch, and the widget doesn't appear in the simulator. The error message I'm getting is:

SendProcessControlEvent:toPid: encountered an error: Error
Domain=com.apple.dt.deviceprocesscontrolservice Code=8 "Failed to show
Widget 'com.mlbench.MyWedgetApp.DateWedget' error: Error
Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "The request to
open "com.apple.springboard" failed."
UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The request was denied by service
delegate (SBMainWorkspace)., BSErrorCodeDescription=RequestDenied,
NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c1f540 {Error
Domain=SBAvocadoDebuggingControllerErrorDomain Code=1 "Failed to get
descriptors for extensionBundleID
(com.mlbench.MyWedgetApp.DateWedget)"
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get descriptors for
extensionBundleID (com.mlbench.MyWedgetApp.DateWedget)}},
FBSOpenApplicationRequestID=0xc66f, NSLocalizedDescription=The request
to open "com.apple.springboard" failed.}."
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to show Widget
'com.mlbench.MyWedgetApp.DateWedget' error: Error
Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "The request to
open "com.apple.springboard" failed."
UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The request was denied by service
delegate (SBMainWorkspace)., BSErrorCodeDescription=RequestDenied,
NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c1f540 {Error
Domain=SBAvocadoDebuggingControllerErrorDomain Code=1 "Failed to get
descriptors for extensionBundleID
(com.mlbench.MyWedgetApp.DateWedget)"
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get descriptors for
extensionBundleID (com.mlbench.MyWedgetApp.DateWedget)}},
FBSOpenApplicationRequestID=0xc66f, NSLocalizedDescription=The request
to open "com.apple.springboard" failed.}.,
NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c1f210 {Error
Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "The request to
open "com.apple.springboard" failed."
UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The request was denied by service
delegate (SBMainWorkspace)., BSErrorCodeDescription=RequestDenied,
NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c1f540 {Error
Domain=SBAvocadoDebuggingControllerErrorDomain Code=1 "Failed to get
descriptors for extensionBundleID
(com.mlbench.MyWedgetApp.DateWedget)"
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get descriptors for
extensionBundleID (com.mlbench.MyWedgetApp.DateWedget)}},
FBSOpenApplicationRequestID=0xc66f, NSLocalizedDescription=The request
to open "com.apple.springboard" failed.}}} Domain: DTXMessage Code: 1
User Info: {
DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-08-17 06:01:48 +0000"; }
System Information
macOS Version 14.5 (Build 23F79) Xcode 15.2 (22503) (Build 15C500b)
Timestamp: 2024-08-17T11:01:48+05:00


Has anyone encountered this error before, or does anyone know how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I was having a similar problem. I simply changed the "kind" property. Earlier I was using similar to bundle identifier. I changed it to "<my_app> widget" and added the "NSExtensionPrincipalClass" in info.plist of the widget target. The error is gone now. I tried to reverse things to see if this was the actual missing part. But now, with the error shown too, the widgets are visible. Weird one. Give it a try once.
